# IIS disable authentication in subfolder

Tags: asp.net, iis, web-config, authorization

In my web.config in application is:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="app/Login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" protection="All" slidingExpiration="true" timeout="10"/>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

In web.config in app folder is:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="Default.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script, Execute"/>
    <staticContent enableDocFooter="false">
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:00:00"/>
    </staticContent>
    <asp enableParentPaths="false" scriptLanguage="VBScript" bufferingOn="true">
      <limits scriptTimeout="00:01:30"/>
      <session allowSessionState="true" timeout="00:20:00"/>
    </asp>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" password="" userName="IUSR"/>
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false" realm="" defaultLogonDomain=""/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <digestAuthentication enabled="false" realm=""/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
    <httpLogging dontLog="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This working, but I want to give access to my_public folder for anonymous users.
In my_public folder is site about.aspx.

In web.config in my_public folder is:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false"/>
    <defaultDocument enabled="true">
      <files>
        <clear/>
        <add value="Default.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <handlers accessPolicy="Read, Script, Execute"/>
    <staticContent enableDocFooter="false">
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:00:00"/>
    </staticContent>
    <asp enableParentPaths="false" scriptLanguage="VBScript" bufferingOn="true">
      <limits scriptTimeout="00:01:30"/>
      <session allowSessionState="true" timeout="00:20:00"/>
    </asp>
    <security>
      <authentication>
        <anonymousAuthentication enabled="true" password="" userName="IUSR"/>
        <basicAuthentication enabled="false" realm="" defaultLogonDomain=""/>
        <windowsAuthentication enabled="false"/>
        <digestAuthentication enabled="false" realm=""/>
      </authentication>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>     
    <allow roles="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</configuration>
```

When user go to my_public/about.aspx always is redirect to app/login.aspx.
User should redirect to my_public/about.aspx when is annonymus.

Answer (score 0):

Change the authorization section on the public web.config to

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

This will allow anonymous access.